GEE outputs different number of groups for each year when performing grouped area calculation in GEE
I wrote a function that aims to calculate the pixel area of each of 19 land cover classes within a masked image's area (MODIS burned area). I mapped the function over 20 years of land cover and burn data to get the total area of each LC class, for each year, within the mask.
The output is confusing: for some years, there are 16 groups (classes) and for others, there are 15 groups (classes) listed. I thought at first that this was because not all classes are present for each year (that is, the area sum = 0), but I saw that amongst the groups included, some had areas of zero. And there are still a couple groups that are not represented at all (I would expect 19 groups for each year, where some groups have zero values.)  Why is this happening? Is this output correct? Here is my code, where 'yearlyBAimgs' is the burned area image collection and 'LCimages' is the land cover image collection (full script is here: code.earthengine.google.co.in/3ce3ab18a68eac306de3d378c9173bb1):
// Use the BA images and LC images to get monthly BA by LC class (summary stats)

/////// Calculate burned area by LC type ///////
var yearlyBA_by_LC = LCimages.map(function(img) {
  
  var LCyear = img.get('year');     
  var LCyearPlus1 = ee.Number(LCyear).add(1); //To get the BA year, get the LC year and add 1. (LC should be 1 year behind BA)
  
  // Filter BA images to match the LC image of the previous year, get pixel area
  var burnedImage = yearlyBAimgs.filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', LCyearPlus1)).first();    //have to add .first() bc it's an Image collection with one image in it, and some functions don't take collections
  var burnedArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6).updateMask(burnedImage.gte(1));
  
  //Add bands so we can reduce
  var BA_LC = burnedArea.addBands(img);
  
  // Get sum of LC area for each year
  var sums = BA_LC.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,            // select the band to group by. In this case, we added the LC band second (see above code chunk), so it should be 1, not 0.
      groupName: 'LC_code'      // this is what we want the resulting property to be called.
    }),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 500,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });
  
  // Return a very flattened list, with an entry for ever LC type and year:
  var asList = ee.List(sums.get('groups')).map(function (pair) {
    return ee.Feature(null, pair).set('year',LCyearPlus1).set('burned_area_SqKm', ee.Dictionary(pair).get('sum'));  
    });
  var outFc = ee.FeatureCollection(asList);
    return outFc;

}).flatten(); 


print('yearlyBA_by_LC', yearlyBA_by_LC);


Can you post a full working example?  This one is incomplete and it's hard to tell what you're seeing.

@NoelGorelick The full script is here, the above code starts on line 153 (I didn't put all the code in my question because it's long): code.earthengine.google.co.in/3ce3ab18a68eac306de3d378c9173bb1
